# Efficiently save Numpy array and load in Javascript as a TypedArray

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way to save a numpy array in Python in a format such that it is possible to load it in JavaScript as a TypedArray? If so, can it also be done in a compressed manner?

If it is not possible to load as a TypedArray, then It would suffice for me if I can load it as a regular array of numbers. The problem I have though is that I have a lot of data generated in Python, so when I save it I need to save it in a space efficient manner. Thus saving as a JSON-object for instance is completely out of the question.

When I want to load the data in Javascript, I only load small portions at a time, so when loaded it is not necessary to be memory efficient.

I know I can save numpy arrays as a .npy or .npz file, but I have not found a way to load .npy or .npz files in JavaScript, nor have I found a different efficient file-format for loading arrays of numbers in Javascript.

Comment: There are a lot of Packages eg. https://github.com/aplbrain/npyjs https://gist.github.com/nvictus/88b3b5bfe587d32ac1ab519fd0009607